# Relativistic inelastic collisions

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose a clay ball of mass $m$, travelling at speed $v=\sqrt{3}c/2$, collides with an identical clay ball that is at rest. They undergo a perfectly inelastic collision.

After performing the relevant calculations (using two separate methods), I found that $M=\sqrt{6}m$ (where $M$ is the mass of the composite ball) and $u=c/\sqrt{3}$ (where $u$ is the speed of the composite ball).

What I don't understand is how the mass of the composite ball can be greater than the sum of the two balls' separate masses, while its speed is also greater. Where does the extra energy come from?

I would have thought that if the mass of composite ball is greater than $2m$, its speed will be smaller than the pre-collision speed of just the one clay ball. I've looked at similar questions online (such as a question apparently from the Feynman lectures, where $v=4c/5$, rather than $\sqrt{3}c/2$), and in each case, if the mass went up then the speed went down and vice versa.

An explanation would be much appreciated (and if I messed up my algebra, pointing that out would also be appreciated).

Note: I didn't use the expression 'rest mass' for any of the masses above because the question didn't either. Not sure if that's relevant/important.

Comment: $c/\sqrt{3}<c\sqrt{3}/2$

Comment: I checked and energy is conserved with your values for $M$ and $u$, so there is no "extra energy" to explain. Can you try to be more precise about exactly why you think there is, with equations? Doing so may lead you to resolve the confusion yourself.

Comment: Massive thanks to Ben51; the problem I was having is that I was comparing $c/\sqrt{3}$ to the classical velocity the composite particle would have, which is $\sqrt{3}c/4$ (this is smaller than the composite particle's relativistic velocity). Comparing it to the original particle's velocity, it is indeed smaller.